# How to make a python function that works as 'mapcar' of lisp

Tags: python, functional-programming, lisp

I want to know how can I make a python function that does the same as `mapcar` of lisp.

From the [mapcar lisp documentation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_mapc_.htm) :

> mapcar operates on successive elements of the lists. function is
>   applied to the first element of each list, then to the second element
>   of each list, and so on. The iteration terminates when the shortest
>   list runs out, and excess elements in other lists are ignored. The
>   value returned by mapcar is a list of the results of successive calls
>   to function.

For example,

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

def sum(firstNumber, secondNumber):
    return firstNumber + secondNumber

sumOfLists = mapcar(sum, list1, list2)

print(sumOfLists)
# [6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map`, and also there is an operator for adding `operator.add`:

```
>>> import operator
>>> list(map(operator.add, list1, list2))
[6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map). `map` takes a function as first argument, and a variable number of **iterable** arguments. The key is that the function should take as many arguments as iterables are given to `map`. That is the only "restriction" to take into account. So, for example:

```
map(lambda x: x+1,         range(10))
map(lambda x, y: x+y,      range(10), range(10))
map(lambda x, y, z: x+y+z, range(10), range(10), range(10))
```

And so on...

Also it can take any other function defined by the user:

```
def checkString(s):
    return isinstance(s, str) and len(s) > 10

>>> list(map(checkString, ["foo", "fooooooooooooooooooooo"]))
[False, True]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how could I do, for example, some mapcar use for a function that check if an element of a list is a string? Or another use that imply the non-use of a basic operation. Just to be sure how to use map function like mapcar in its totality.

Comment: @Javierdds, I just expanded the answer

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved in this way: `sumOfLists = map(sum, zip(list1, list2))`
You also do not need to define the `sum` function, as it is built-in.